# how to fix force close error in android app

Tags: android

my app have force close error and i don't know how to fix it

i user this code before and it's works but now have force close error

how to fix this force close?

when app wants to stat, force close happens

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pB1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="2dip" />
```

my activity:

```
package com.microweb.gapiha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.TabHost;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //keep screen on and alive
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("aval").setIndicator("social ").setContent(new Intent(this  ,IntroActivity.class )));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("dovom").setIndicator("chat").setContent(new Intent(this ,ChatActivity.class )));           
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("sevom").setIndicator("chat 2 ").setContent(new Intent(this ,RandomActivity.class )));             
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);   

}

}
```

logcat:

```
   08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-07 08:23:03.887: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-07 08:23:03.947: E/StrictMode(646):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-07 08:23:03.947: W/ActivityManager(288): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4100b7e8
```

i uploaded this files and log cat too :
[download my codes and log cat error form 4shared](http://www.4shared.com/zip/a94CGvIF/codes.html)

Comment: post stacktrace in your post, not in a zip hosted somewhere.

Comment: i don't know how to do this

Comment: Windows -> Show View -> Others -> Android -> LogCat

Comment: post error message here

Comment: i edit my post... see log cat

Comment: Can you put full logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity_main.xml should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

         <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

      </LinearLayout>    
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I just checked the logcat file you uploaded on 4shared,

Comment: You should also change your activity

Comment: TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);